# Recently viewed products from all users

Tags: product, widgets, ce-1.4.1.1

Is it possible to configure the recently viewed products widget to show the products that all visitors have recently viewed? The regular widget only shows the products which you have viewed yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the block class outputting the recently viewed products `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed` you can see the `_toHtml` method uses the `getItemsCollection` method from `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract`.

In this class the collection is actually retrieved and on line 124 the customer ID is added to the collection as a filtering.

So a good place to start would be to rewrite the `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract` to a custom extension and modify the collection retrieval excluding the customer filter.

Optionally you could copy this file to local and modify it but that might lead to issues when upgrading to a newer version of Magento (and is also just a bad practice in general)