# Magento 2 How To Get Recently View Product Collection All Users

Tags: magento-2.1, recently-viewed

How can i configure the recently viewed products widget to show the products that all visitors recently viewed

Ref:[Recently viewed products from all users](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/recently-viewed-products-from-all-users)

Let me know how can i do it

Comment: Please check this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199889/magento-2-2-0-display-recently-viewed-products-block-on-product-detail-page

Comment: Hai thanks for your ans, But i want to show the products that all visitors recently viewed  not single user recently viewed